# Who was responsible for the correct production of a Mesopotamian 'cubit rod' and whose fingers where used as the standard?

Tags: technology, mesopotamia, sumer

Who was responsible for the correct production of a Mesopotamian 'cubit rod' and whose fingers where used as the standard?

Wikipedia notes that the standards changed but gives no source of these claims.

> Ancient Mesopotamian units of measurement originated in the loosely
> organized city-states of Early Dynastic Sumer. Each city, kingdom and
> trade guild had its own standards until the formation of the Akkadian
> Empire when Sargon of Akkad issued a common standard. This standard
> was improved by Naram-Sin, but fell into disuse after the Akkadian
> Empire dissolved. The standard of Naram-Sin was readopted in the Ur
> III period by the Nanše Hymn which reduced a plethora of multiple
> standards to a few agreed upon common groupings. <sub>[Wiki page on Cubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubit#Ancient_Mesopotamian_units_of_measurement)</sub>

The cubit rod was basically a measure stick, and Ancient Sumer [certainly was not the only culture to utilize one.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measuring_rod#Ancient_Sumer) But I did find that it was important enough that Inanna (also known as the goddess Ishtar) carried a Lapis Lazuli measurement rod:

> She placed twin egg-shaped beads on her breast. She covered her body with a pala dress, the garment of ladyship. She placed mascara which is called "Let a man come, let him come" on her eyes. She pulled the pectoral which is called "Come, man, come" over her breast. She placed a golden ring on her hand. **She held the lapis-lazuli measuring rod and measuring line in her hand.** 26-27. Inana travelled towards the underworld. Her minister Ninšubur travelled behind her.<sub>[Inana's descent to the nether world](https://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/cgi-bin/etcsl.cgi?text=t.1.4.1#)</sub>

A lot of tablets have been preserved but not translated. I am wondering if there is any written record on whose fingers where the standard and who was ultimately responsible for the production of these measurement sticks. I'm having a hard time finding any sources. If this question is too broad I'm willing to narrow it down too how Sargon implemented his measurements and who or what was the source of the measurements.

Comment: I suspect the answer was that in those time periods, people didn't care enough about accuracy to require a "standard" hand.

Comment: @GorttheRobot: They most certainly did care. Not for all purposes, of course, but when it comes to things like trade, taxation, wages, rations or land disputes, honest and accurate standardized measurements become very important. It's somewhat telling that the oldest known Sumerian proto-cuneiform tablets, from before the development of true phonetic writing, are pretty much all tables of numerical accounts and measurements. Basically, writing evolved out of accounting.